# How to do auto click action for asp login control

Tags: asp.net

No very familiar with asp.net, but I have to modify an old asp.net web app. The app has a pretty standard asp login control screen with username, password and a login button with CommandName = "Login".

The modification would be - when the Windows login user is a domain user, I then set a specific username/password and automatically log in the user to the home page. I tried not to change the code too much because ValidateUser() has special logic in it.

I can get the domain user info using:
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;

and set default user/pass using
this.Login1.UserName = "myuser";
(TextBox)this.Login1.FindControl("Password").Attributes.Add("value", "mypass");

But I don't know how to execute the click action of login button (asp ImageButton.)

Any help will be appreciated.